# With the android editText control is there a simple way to display only numbers?

Tags: android, contacts, android-edittext

I have a simple app that allows the user to push a button that brings up the list of contacts.  They select the contact and the application then puts the phone number into an edit text control.  This all works like a charm.

However, I notice that the phone number that is retrieved has 'punctuation' marks in it: 123.456.7890 or 123-456-7890 is returned verbatim with the dots and dashes included.

Is there a simple way to strip out non-numeric entry before displaying back to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to manipulate the string using standard Java String functions to remove non numbers.

i.e.

```
myString.replaceAll("\D", "");
```

\D is a regex that should match anything that isn't a digit.  See [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) docs.

[replaceAll](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will replace all instances of the regex with whatever you provide as the second param.